# immutableJS+React Get key of iterable while mapping

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

There is OrderedMap immutablejs object:

```
{
        "country": {
            "value": "US",
            "locked": false,
            "history": null
        },
        "city": {
            "value": "NY",
            "locked": false,
            "history": [
                {
                    "value": "LA",
                    "date": 1447366980
                },
                {
                    "value": "WA",
                    "date": 1447331640
                }
            ]
        },

        "event_title": {
            "value": "some text",
            "locked": false,
            "history": null
        },
        "place": {
            "value":"some text",
            "locked": false,
            "history":null
        }
}
```

Need to map it to React components:

```
const fields = res.map(item => <Field name={%KEY_NEED_HERE%} rest={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />)
```

How to get key of iterable and send it to name of Field? Somethng like

```
<Field name={city} rest={item} />
```

Plz, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd argument passed to the mapper is the key, so you can do this:

```
const fields = res.map((item, key) => <Field name={key} rest={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the end result to  be `name='NY'` then you would need to pass it `name={item.getIn(['city', 'value']}`.

`getIn` is a method that is available to all Immutable objects. Check the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/getIn) for more